What electrical connection for a ceiling mounted fan forced industrial heater?
What type of wire should I use for a 5,000 watt 240 v 30amp heater?
Can I use  a double 30amp internal common trip breaker or a double 20amp breaker which I have both?
Also what does it mean when a double breaker says common trip breaker?

You have multiple questions here. The real question that needs an answer is what size wire is needed to run to your heater.
The math works like this 5000w/ 240v+ 20.83A.  The breaker cannot be a 20A so that is out. You need the 30A breaker. (If derated to 80% that is 24A. Still big enough for your heater.)
For a 30A breaker you need to run 10 gauge wire.(If the run from breaker to appliance is over 100 feet go to 8 gauge).
You then have wire that is rated to carry the amperage draw of the appliance and a breaker that will protect the wire if it were to get overheated.
A common trip breaker is internally connected so if one side trips the other side does as well.

You need the 30 amp breaker because of derating for the wires.
A common trip means both sides of the breaker trip together, making sure all power is shut off.
For 30 amps, you want minimum of 10 gauge copper wire, but can use larger.
If the heater does not use neutral, you can use 10/2(plus ground) and mark the white wire at both end black or red. Using the white wire as a second hot.  Can use tape, paint, marking pens.
